# does not implement the WriteToStreamAsync method

Tags: json.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a MVC4 api using the release canidate. The error I get when I do a GET with a Content-Type: application/json I get this error: The media type formatter of type 'JsonNetFormatter' does not support writing because it does not implement the WriteToStreamAsync method.

I do believe I am!

```
public Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented,
                                                      new JsonConverter[1] { new IsoDateTimeConverter() });

            byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json);
            stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        });

        return task;
    }
```

I've seen an example that overrides this method, but I get an error that there is no suitable method to override.  I'm guessing it's a versioning issue with System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll but I've double checked the version and it looks good:

```
// Type: System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter
// Assembly: System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// Assembly location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
```

Comment: Yes. Signature changed from beta to RC. So your problem solved?

Comment: I'm not sure which one is the new interface. The "HttpContent" version is the one to use in the future, right (NOT the "HttpContentHeaders")?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in how I implemented the method. just like the error said. HttpContent shoud be HttpContentHeaders changed to:

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value,
                                    Stream stream,
                                    HttpContentHeaders content,
                                    TransportContext transportContext)
```